# How pass data to Angular from a external system with a post url?

Tags: angular, flutter

My question is simple I have an application in Flutter that will use a checkout payment and I want to use my webpage already maded in angular to gain some time.

So I need to pass some data from user, product and credit card. The problem is that Angular don't accept post methods i guess, because when i try go to the url i get:

**Cannot POST /**

I don't want to send with GET parameters because of security, what are the best approaches to make this work?

If no solution exists for this I must make a simple HTML page with PHP and JS.

Comment: Are you trying to POST to an api? Angular can post things

Comment: No, I have a Flutter mobile app and need to post some data to an Angular App, it is a front end app not API. I need to make a POST request from FLUTTER to ANGULAR

Comment: That won't work. You're assuming Angular has direct access to a database which it doesn't. Angular is just front end. You would need to have a separate api (nothing to do with Angular) and POST your data off to that. Then if you wish to recall any data on the Angular pages you will need to recall that via a guid.

Comment: I guess you guys don't understand, in my Angular is just a simple payment form ( ON FRONTEND ) that I made and I want just send a security data from a webview in Flutter.

Comment: If you were merely sending basic details like first name and last name you PROBABLY could get away with sending it via querystrings on the address bar. But there is physically no way to send it from your mobile app as an object to an angular app. Even if you could it wouldn't be secure enough (not with credit card info). You would still need to have an api to act as a middleman in this scenerio.

Comment: But is it such a big deal to ask them to enter their details on another screen? Loads of apps do this.

Comment: I made the payment page in Angular and now I will make everything again from a simple HTML with PHP, it is sad.

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward because my payment method use a javascript library and Flutter don't use it, so I need to make a webview approach to gain some time because is a complex page